# How to determine why via Starlink cannot access 67.208.88.200

Tags: networking, routing

I have recently obtained starlink and I have a purchased application roboform

Roboform syncs passwords with the online site "online.roboform.com"  but this does not work when connected via starlink

I have logged a call with Roboform - but I'm not sure it is there problem - I see no way to log calls to Starlink

It was suggested elsewhere I could be using a previously blacklisted address

I did stow and unstow the starlink in the hope it would get a new IP address but this did not work (I still have the same IP reported by whatsmyip )

I have temporarily setup a static route to 67.208.88.200 via by backup link  (Satellite NBN ) and sync is now working , but if I get a new IP assigned from the satelliteNBN it will stop working

Anyone have any any other ideas of what I can do?

https://start.roboform.com/#view=folder&type=login  is accesible

So I have tracerouted to both

When connected via starlink

```
   Tracing route to online.roboform.com [67.208.88.200]   over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.33.1
  2     4 ms     4 ms     9 ms  192.168.1.1
  3    46 ms    50 ms    39 ms  100.64.0.1
  4    53 ms    44 ms    40 ms  172.16.249.14
  5    48 ms    56 ms    48 ms  149.19.108.171
  6    49 ms    40 ms    44 ms  8.245.128.225
  7    55 ms    54 ms    53 ms  4.69.208.206
  8    93 ms   109 ms    54 ms  4.68.38.206
  9     *      191 ms     *     129.250.2.220
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *      223 ms   220 ms  129.250.4.150
 12   270 ms   262 ms   269 ms  129.250.5.16
 13   269 ms   264 ms   268 ms  129.250.2.26
 14   282 ms   279 ms   284 ms  129.250.2.167
 15   274 ms   276 ms   281 ms  129.250.3.51
 16   281 ms   277 ms   298 ms  129.250.194.106
 17   293 ms   280 ms   295 ms  108.60.151.223
 18   297 ms   290 ms   294 ms  205.251.127.69
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

At the same time when connected via Starlink I can ping start.roboform.com
Tracing route to start.roboform.com [38.127.147.71] over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  4    45 ms    63 ms    58 ms  172.16.249.14
  5    45 ms    57 ms    49 ms  149.19.108.169
  6    68 ms    45 ms    43 ms  8.244.64.25
  7   216 ms   246 ms   223 ms  4.69.219.206
  8   212 ms   202 ms   207 ms  154.54.10.245
  9   218 ms   218 ms   221 ms  154.54.86.109
 10   228 ms   242 ms   232 ms  154.54.42.98
 11   291 ms   240 ms   238 ms  154.54.31.90
 12   268 ms   255 ms   272 ms  154.54.44.170
 13   260 ms   267 ms   261 ms  154.54.7.130
 14   278 ms   307 ms   280 ms  154.54.82.254
 15   272 ms   269 ms   270 ms  154.54.46.194
 16   285 ms   272 ms   271 ms  38.127.147.71
```

But When connected via a Telstra NBN (at the same time )   I can tracert to BOTH

```
Tracing route to online.roboform.com [67.208.88.200] over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.240
  2    10 ms    13 ms    13 ms  58.162.26.200
  3    16 ms    13 ms     9 ms  203.50.61.129
  4    15 ms    12 ms    10 ms  203.50.61.128
  5    27 ms    26 ms    19 ms  203.50.11.124
  6    29 ms    23 ms    26 ms  203.50.6.93
  7    26 ms    22 ms    23 ms  203.50.13.98
  8    22 ms    25 ms    28 ms  203.50.13.98
  9    23 ms    36 ms    31 ms  202.84.222.130
 10   164 ms   160 ms   158 ms  202.84.222.130
 11   158 ms   158 ms   158 ms  202.84.141.225
 12   158 ms   159 ms   160 ms  202.84.141.225
 13   157 ms   164 ms   158 ms  202.84.253.86
 14   157 ms   160 ms   158 ms  62.115.162.134
 15   213 ms   214 ms   214 ms  62.115.114.87
 16   213 ms   213 ms   214 ms  62.115.123.123
 17   223 ms   218 ms   282 ms  62.115.183.241
 18     *      222 ms     *     66.231.176.30
 19   218 ms   218 ms   220 ms  205.251.126.103
 20   218 ms   218 ms   219 ms  67.208.88.200
Trace complete.
```

and
Tracing route to start.roboform.com [38.127.147.71] over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.240
  2    10 ms     9 ms     8 ms  58.162.26.200
  3     8 ms    16 ms    12 ms  203.50.61.129
  4    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  203.50.61.128
  5    24 ms    23 ms    23 ms  203.50.11.124
  6    25 ms    23 ms    23 ms  203.50.6.93
  7    35 ms    29 ms    23 ms  203.50.13.98
  8    24 ms    23 ms    23 ms  203.50.13.98
  9    24 ms    23 ms    23 ms  202.84.222.130
 10   159 ms   159 ms   158 ms  202.84.222.130
 11   160 ms   159 ms   159 ms  202.84.141.225
 12   158 ms   159 ms   160 ms  202.84.141.225
 13   158 ms   158 ms   159 ms  202.84.253.86
 14   158 ms   158 ms   157 ms  62.115.162.134
 15   158 ms   159 ms   159 ms  80.239.160.65
 16   158 ms   159 ms   158 ms  154.54.42.101
 17   170 ms   170 ms   171 ms  154.54.44.85
 18   188 ms   188 ms   187 ms  154.54.42.66
 19   195 ms   196 ms   195 ms  154.54.29.221
 20   206 ms   206 ms   205 ms  154.54.28.69
 21   221 ms   220 ms   221 ms  154.54.7.157
 22   221 ms   221 ms   220 ms  154.54.46.190
 23   222 ms   221 ms   221 ms  38.127.147.71
Trace complete.
```

Comment: If you use a different DNS provider are the results any different?

Comment: the Telstra NBN and the Starlink are different DNS servers - but  the resolved addresses are the same - so essentially no the DNS resolution is unchanged between them

Comment: If you use a DNS server like Google does anything change?

Comment: I should of said Starlink is using googles DNS (8.8.8.8)

Comment: I am trying to determine if the problem is your DNS provider, or your ISP itself, so have you tried using a different DNS provider then the one you are currently using which is apparently Google (knowing that 4 hours ago I would have saved some time suggesting something more specific).

Comment: Don't use plain traceroute, use the TCP switch , and trace on either port 443, or whatever port it uses. And try telnetting to the port and see what happens. FWIW, I tried that and the system being hit just before it, was also 205.251.126.103. This could be a routing propblem with Starlink, and you would be best to contact them.

Comment: As I said "telstra NBN and the Starlink are different DNS servers" so they are using different DNS servers , and they are resolving to the same IP so it is not a DNS problem

Comment: Whilst I have no proof I believe this is most likely due to an error in the Roboform infrastructure - I logged a call and they have responded saying they had connectivity issues and I should try a different ISP - the problem has resolved itself with ping and tracert connection to 67.208.88.200  now working from both ISPs